# SystemException with Interpolation

Tags: warning-messages, interpolation

Consider the following sample code

```
Interpolation[{Range[20], 2*Range[20]}];
```

> `Interpolation::indim: The coordinates do not lie on a structured tensor product grid. >>`

which should not work because of the error explained in the warning message. For larger vectors (of length greater or equal to 66) result is completely different

```
With[{n = 66}, Interpolation[{Range[n], 2*Range[n]}]]
```

> `SystemException["InterpolationLimit", {65, 1}]`

without warning message. Is this *bug* reproducible on newer versions of *Mathematica* or on other systems (I'm working on version 10.0 under OSX), and what may be a reason of that? (Corrected code, e.g. `With[{n = 66}, Interpolation[{{0,Range[n]}, {1,2*Range[n]}}]]` works with any nonnegative `n`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is due to an old `Interpolation` syntax for specifying multidimensional data as

$$\{\{x_1, y_1, z_1, \ldots, f_1\}, \{x_2, y_2, z_2,\ldots, f_2\}, \ldots \}$$
meaning that $f_i$ is the desired function value at the point $\{x_i, y_i, z_i, \ldots \}$ where the points lie on a structured tensor product grid.

This syntax was deprecated a long time ago, but is still accepted for backward compatibility (see also the legacy [reference page](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/Interpolation)). For example,

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, t, Times[x, y, z, t]}, {x, 4}, {y, 4}, {z, 4}, {t, 4}], 3];
if = Interpolation[data];
if[4, 4, 4, 4]

(* 256 *)
```

The input from the question requests a function that takes the value $66$ at the point $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 65\}$ and $132$ at the point $\{2, 4, 6, \ldots, 130\}$. Getting a `SystemException` is not unreasonable, since interpolating in 65 or more dimensions is somewhat extreme.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. What do you mean by 'is still accepted'? The  `Interpolation[{{x1, y1, z1, ..., f1}, ...}]` doesn't work but just returns its input.

Comment: @mmal That it still works as it used to. Answer updated for clarity.